# Shared Library, vcpkg, cmake and linking

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, linker-errors, vcpkg

I have installed package "spdlog" from vcpkg manager, successfully linked with the library by providing CMake instruction and generated foo.dll and foo.dll.a

Now, I use these dll's in my application by linking with foo.dll

1. spdlog headers (used in foo.dll) can not be found by my application `fooapp` now.
2. If I use `target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE spdlog::spdlog spdlog::spdlog_header_only)` in CmakeLists.txt of `fooapp`, include error is gone. But Linker complains that it can't find the `foo.dll.a` at `xxx` path. What is confusing that at `xxx` path the `.dll.a` file is present.  (***Don't know if its correct, just did to let cmake find spdlog headers as per vcpkg instructions***)

Note: If I remove dependency of `spdlog` in `foo.dll` and try simple `cout` all works fine. Linker can find and link `foo.dll.a` and successfully make `fooapp.exe`. This is becoming too confusing for me now and I can't find good stack answers related to this. `spdlog` here is just a reference, It can be any other package by vcpkg.

a) Are dll headers also the dependency of applications?
b) Why `.dll.a` is not found, It is at the exact location for what it complains about.
c) Why removing the dependency of `spdlog` make it all work again?

Comment: Do not *describe*, the code: instead add the code into the question post (in form of [mcve]). Do not *describe* the error message: instead add the **exact error message** into the question post.

Comment: wild guess: Missing `-DVPCKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw-dynamic`?

Comment: it's included. I used spdlog as submodule instead of vcpkg and it works fine.